# Favorite emacs minor mode?

Tags: emacs

I just discovered [tabbar](http://github.com/davidswelt/aquamacs-emacs/blob/master/aquamacs/src/site-lisp/tabbar/tabbar.el), a minor mode that provides firefox like tabs in emacs.
I also modify org-mode into a minor mode and use it with other major modes for code folding and organizing my code, for example:  ([ahk-org-mode](http://github.com/tinku99/ahk-org-mode) )
What are your favorite minor modes.

Are there major modes that you have turned into minor modes so you can use them with other major modes ?

Comment: are you using aquamacs? or does this work with gnu emacs too?

Comment: I have tabbar.el working on gnu-emacs on windows xp sp2, without modification.

Comment: org-mode as a minor mode, I've been looking for this

Comment: While this is a fun topic, it is a classic example of a question that would have been closed in about 5 minutes given the current forum participators -- the current congregation would have stamped this as *opinion* and not a classic programming question.  The current clan would have down-voted also.  I wish I would have been around in 2010 to enjoy the good old days.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- [autopair](https://github.com/capitaomorte/autopair) - Automatically pair braces and quotes in emacs like TextMate
- [paredit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit) - ultimate sexp editing mode, one cannot do serious Lisp programming without it
- [flyspell](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlySpell) and cousing flyspell-prog-mode - great on the fly spellchecking
- [eldoc](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElDoc) - on the fly hints about function parameters, etc in several languages like Emacs Lisp, Perl...
- [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) - template expansion framework ala TextMate bundles
- [auto-revert-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Reverting.html) - reverts buffers, if underlying files have been changed externally
- [hl-line](http://emacsblog.org/2007/04/09/highlight-the-current-line/) - highlights the current line
- [windmove](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove) - easier navigation between many open windows in Emacs
- [show-paren-mode](http://emacsblog.org/2007/08/07/quick-tip-show-paren-mode/) - highlight matching parenthesis, making it easier to spot errors with their pairing

All those minor modes are simply Godsend! I cannot live without them and they make my whole editing experience that much more enjoyable and productive...

Btw you can see much of the customizations and modes that I use in my configuration publicly available [here](http://github.com/bbatsov/emacs)(most of the minor mode stuff is in misc-config.el). I also recommend to everyone to follow the excellent blog [Emacs Fu](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/), when I've picked many interesting modes over the past couple of years.

Comment: Flyspell makes a lot of general editing a lot nicer to do.

Answer (score 5):

I like auto-complete (for code completion): http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/

Answer (score 2):

- [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) mostly for command completion.
- [Flymake](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlyMake) for simple syntax checks.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses matching, my favorite of which is [`mic-paren`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MicParen).

Answer (score 0):

- [Anaconda](https://github.com/proofit404/anaconda-mode)
- [Anzu](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-anzu)
- [Company](http://company-mode.github.io/)
- [Diff-Hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl)
- [Flycheck](http://www.flycheck.org/)
- Flyspell
- [Multiple cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el)
- [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm)
- [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile)
- [Smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens)
- [Yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet)
- [Undo-Tree](http://www.dr-qubit.org/emacs.php#undo-tree)
- [Slime](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Emacs for a long time and I have to say that my configuration has changed several times because of changing the main Programming language, related tools, etc. However, regardless of the tasks you are performing with Emacs the following minor-modes would improve your productivity.

1. [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm)

The helm mode basically could be used to auto-complete anything (actually it's a fork for the original anything.el mode). You can use it for quick buffer switch, opening files or switching quickly to a file on any project when combined with the projectile mode. You need just to know few letters of what you would like to do helm will auto-complete an narrow the selection list keeping only entries that match with your criteria. You can enable the fuzzy behavior for several functionalities which is very powerful.
For more details:

http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html

2. [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile)

If you are a developer that works with several code branches, etc this is a must. With projectile you can easily switch between the different projects, open files that belong to your current project, etc. Combined with Helm it offers a very powerful tool to navigate easily in any project even if you are not familiar with the code tree structure.

http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html

3. [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl)

Very interesting mode with minimal interface that lets you navigate your changes when you are working on a file with version control. It supports the main VCS like subversion, git, mercurial. etc. Additionally you revert separate chucks of code, see the differences with the repository and more features.

4. [iedit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Iedit)
5. [diminuish](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com.es/2010/05/cleaning-up-mode-line.html)
6. [Uniquify](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/uniquifymirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/uniquify.el)

These are more or less the minor modes I normally use. The following modes/configurations are also useful if you are working with the spicified programming language:

1. C/C++

Just install the [irony-mode](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode) and install the [auto-complete](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete) mode.

2. [C#](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-emacs)

The omnisharp mode basically lets you use the powerful VisualStudio's intellisense auto-completion from your emacs. You just need to run the omnisharp server with your .sln and that's all!. Normally I combine it with the company auto-complete mode.

3. Python

I'm using [Jedi](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi) and it works like a charm.